# Comparing test and validation ROC curves statistically

Tags: neural-networks, roc, model-comparison

So I have two sets of data my validation set and my test set. I have a neural network model that was tuned on the validation set and then finally tested on the test set and I got similar results in both the validation and test set.

I was wondering if there is was a typical way of comparing the ROC curve where essentially I will be using the same model but on two different data sets to show they are similar. The idea being I would like to show I'm not over or underfitting to the validation set. I saw one paper do something along these lines but it was unclear what statistical test they used.

Any suggestions on what method I could look at?

Comment: Can a Mann-Whitney U test be used on both sets of predictions? I think the paper I mentioned seemed to suggest they used that.

Comment: ROC curves or areas under the curves?

Comment: Well, I guess ROC Curves would be better, although the area would be ok if its sufficient to compare the area under the curve and conclude the results are similar?

Comment: You have to decide what interests you. Some argue that ROC curves are worthless except for the fact that the AUC is equal to the concordance index.

Comment: If you want to compare AUROC there is the DeLong test. This is implemented in R's pROC package.  That package implements DeLong, bootstrap, and Venkatraman tests. You can also search and find a few blogs on DeLong test explaining it. As others mentioned, AUROC might not be the best stat to use to test if the model will generalize.

Answer (score 2):

ROC curves are not something you validate.  Instead validate absolute predictive accuracy by estimating a smooth calibration curve (predicted probability vs. actual probability that Y=1).  This is discussed [here](https://hbiostat.org/rms) in the book and course notes.  You can validate the ROC area (c-index; Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney concordance probability) as a measure of pure discrimination.   But [other indexes](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue) are better.